# MyBatis - Using Spring Transactions with Batch Operations

Tags: java, spring, transactions, mybatis

I am migrating from iBatis 2.3 to MyBatis 3.2.8.  Everything is going well, but I do have a question when it comes to transactions and batch operations. Towards the bottom of https://mybatis.github.io/spring/sqlsession.html, it says:

> The caveat to this form is that there cannot be an existing transaction running >with a different ExecutorType when this method is called. Either ensure that >calls to SqlSessionTemplates with different executor types run in a separate >transaction (e.g. with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW) or completely outside of a >transaction.

I have a service call that is annotated with @Transactional that makes multiple Dao Calls:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveMassUploadOrder(List<IndividualOrder> orders) {
   List<IndividualOrderItem> ioItems = new ArrayList<IndividualOrderItem>();
   for (IndividualOrder order : orders) {
      ioItems.addAll(order.getIoItems());
   }
   individualOrderDao.insertBatch(orders);
   individualOrderItemDao.insertBatch(ioItems);
}
```

The DAOs would look like:

```
public class IndividualOrderDAOImpl  implements IndividualOrderDAO{
   private SqlSession sqlSession;

   public void setSqlSession(SqlSession sqlSession) {
      this.sqlSession = sqlSession;
   }

   public void insertBatch(final List<IndividualOrder> orders) {
      for (IndividualOrder order: orders){
         sqlSession.insert("namespace.insert", order);
    }
}
```

}

The config looks like:

```
<bean id="batchSqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">     
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="doeSqlSessionFactory" />
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
</bean>
<bean id="individualOrderDao" class="com.doe.mybatis.jdoe.dao.IndividualOrderDAOImpl">
    <property name="sqlSession" ref="batchSqlSession" />
</bean>
<bean id="individualOrderItemDao" class="com.doe.mybatis.jdoe.dao.IndividualOrderItemDAOImpl">
   <property name="sqlSession" ref="batchSqlSession" />
</bean>
```

So - would the multiple DAO calls within this service call be OK since the service is opening a transaction and its not working in a batch mode and making calls to these DAOs? Obviously, I am wanting the call to this service to not  actually insert any orders or order items if there is a failure somewhere during the execution.

I haven't migrated these DAOs yet, and I can probably set up a catastrophic event during a test batch insert and check the data, I was just wanting to get some other opinions before I started to see if I have to set this up differently or not.

Any help appreciated!